# <!DOCTYPE HTML> Google Maps Error or Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps, doctype

I'm stuck here. I have a html/javascript template I downloaded and it has a sliding sidebar etc using javascript. I have also just created a Map using Google api on this template.

When I have

< !DOCTYPE HTML>

at the top of my html (now php) page, the Embedded Google Map does not work. When I don't have it there the javascript code relating to the sidebar functions does not work. Any ideas?

**ANSWER:**

I Found a work arround. Instead of using 50% for the div for the Google Map I changed it to absolute value of 500px. This corrected the issue.

Comment: Without codes no one can help you

Comment: I don't know where in the javascript code it could be and there is a lot of it. And the google api map code is just the basic embed map code. Simply adding the DOCTYPE to the top of the page will disable the Embedded Google Map and removing it will disable some Javascript functions. I thought this would be an issue that others may know about.